# Uibutton in UitableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have added a `uibutton` in every row of `uitableview`, Now, whenever a user clicks on any of the button in `uitableview`, I want to remove that button.  Please help me to solve this, I have added the button tag with `indexPath.row` and then fire a method that contains a mutable array, then I add the [sender tag] into mutable array and reload the tableview and in cell for row, I am checking whether the array contains the object, if yes I place a label else a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add below code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method 
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(230, 2, 60, 25);
    myButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myButton setTitle:@"Click to remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];


//button action metod
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable suggestions, but what i want is like this : - (IBAction)buttonClicked :(id)sender { [self requestToTheServerToAddThisFriend] if i get response as success at that time i want to remove the uibutton and place a label on that row, i came to know about the removeFromSuperView method but i also want to place a label, this is an overhead for me, please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it, hope so this will work for you also

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
    {
        UIButton *mybutton =(UIButton *)sender;
        [mybutton removeFromSuperview];
    }

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(PullDownTableView *)tableView cellInRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }

    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(230, 2, 60, 25);
    [myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:headerButton];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: UIButton requires unique identifier to delete the tapped UIButton.

Comment: @iApple: Thanks for response, what i think a Unique identifier is necessary, if we want to delete any Button with specific description. But in this case whichever button is tapped that should be removed/deleted.So in ButtonAction whoever is Sender will be deleted.Guide me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

UIButton is a subclass of the UIView class. It has the -removeFromSuperview method. Please note that you will have to check if the cell has had its button removed on the -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

**myButton.tag = indexPath.row;** is required to identify the UIButton to delete. So, set an unique tag to each created UIButtons in UITableViewCell.

Below is the **modified** sample code...

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(230, 2, 60, 25);
myButton.tag = indexPath.row;
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:headerButton];
```

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable suggestions, but what i want is like this : - (IBAction)buttonClicked :(id)sender { [self requestToTheServerToAddThisFriend] if i get response as success at that time i want to remove the uibutton and place a label on that row, i came to know about the removeFromSuperView method but i also want to place a label, this is an overhead for me, please give me some suggestions.